# convert hex characters in a file to ASCII using a shell script

Tags: shell, hex, printf, ascii

I have a file `values` who contains a string of hex characters.

`\x41\x42\x43\x44\x45`

I can encode it to the binary values using for example `printf`:

`printf $(cat values)`----------- output ---------> `ABCDE`

This works perfectly on the terminal, but it doesn't work inside a script:

```
#!/bin/sh
printf $(cat values)
```

Result:

```
$ ./script.sh
\x41\x42\x43\x44\x45
```

I would like to know why it doesn't work and how to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because `printf` used in bash isn't the same as in sh. For a quick fix, simply replace `#!/bin/sh` by `#!/bin/bash`. As long as you don't care about full compliance with `/bin/sh`, it may be an easy solution.

However, if you really want to use the `sh` interpreter, then use something like:

```
/bin/echo -e "\x40"
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using #!/bin/bash and not #!/bin/sh? I can't tell from your question, but it doesn't seem as if you need to use sh instead of bash.